# how to elimate the need for a large number of if elif else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

My script uses a if elif else check to determine which array item to look at for crafting values. The issue is there are a total of 24 elif statements to allow for a total of 26 choices, (1 for the if, 1 for error catching). What I'm trying to figure out is how to reduce the number of elif statements so the code is better structured.

```
while choice == 0:
    choice = input("Choose a block (Enter only the Number):")
    if not choice.isalpha(): # Makes sure that the input is a number and not a string.
        choice = int(choice)
    else:
        choice = 0
        print("Thats not a number. Choose a number Numbnuts.")
    if choice == 1:
        print("\n",block[0])
    elif choice == 2:
        print("\n",block[1])
    elif choice == 3:
        print("\n",block[2])
    elif choice == 4:
        print("\n",block[6])
    elif choice == 5:
        print("\n",block[7])
    elif choice == 6:
        print("\n",block[8])
    elif choice == 7:
        print("\n",block[3])
    elif choice == 8:
        print("\n",block[4])
    elif choice == 9:
        print("\n",block[5])
    elif choice == 10:
        print("\n",block[9])
    elif choice == 11:
        print("\n", block[10])
    elif choice == 12:
        print("\n", block[11])
    elif choice == 13:
        print("\n",block[12])
    elif choice == 14:
        print("\n",block[13])
    elif choice == 15:
        print("\n",block[14])
    elif choice == 16:
        print("\n",block[15])
    elif choice == 17:
        print("\n",block[16])
    elif choice == 18:
        print("\n",block[17])
    elif choice == 19:
        print("\n",block[18])
    elif choice == 20:
        print("\n",block[19])
    elif choice == 21:
        print("\n",block[20])
    elif choice == 22:
        print("\n", block[21])
    elif choice == 23:
        print("\n", block[22])
    elif choice == 24:
        print("\n",block[23])
    elif choice == 25:
        print("\n",block[24])
    elif choice == 26:
        print("\n",block[25])
```

Comment: Use a table:   `print("\n", block[position[choice]])`. Check that `choice` is in range first.

Comment: Wait, what's up with `elif choice == 4: print("\n",block[6])`? Why is it not `print("\n", block[3])`? Same for `choice in {5,6,7,8,9}`

Comment: @ForceBru That is probably the reason why Jaxer can't just write `print("\n", block[choice - 1])`.

Comment: Since there are only two displacement, a conditional can handle it: if `choice` is below 4, subtract 1, otherwise subtract 2.  It's a question of is this all expected to change, and are you willing to maintain the changing formula rather than a changing table.  Also, would the mapping ever be configurable at run-time, so that it can change while the program stays the same.

Comment: @ForceBru I put the array calls wrong, I do mean to change that so that it is correct later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for structure:

```
elif choice == 12:
    print("\n", block[11])
elif choice == 13:
    print("\n",block[12])
elif choice == 14:
    print("\n",block[13])
elif choice == 15:
    print("\n",block[14])
elif choice == 16:
    print("\n",block[15])
```

Clearly, this is the same as;

```
print("\n", block[choice - 1])
```

**However**, for `choice in {4,5,6,7,8,9}` the logic isn't that simple, so you could keep the `if`s:

```
if choice == 4:
        print("\n",block[6])
elif choice == 5:
        print("\n",block[7])
elif choice == 6:
        print("\n",block[8])
elif choice == 7:
        print("\n",block[3])
elif choice == 8:
        print("\n",block[4])
elif choice == 9:
        print("\n",block[5])
else:
        print("\n", block[choice - 1])
```

You could also go a step deeper: for `choice in {4,5,6}` the index is `choice-2`, and for `choice in {7,8,9}` the index is `choice-4`:

```
if choice in {4,5,6}:
   idx = choice - 2
elif choice in {7,8,9}:
   idx = choice - 4
else:
   idx = choice - 1

print("\n", block[idx])
```

Comment: It's not always `choice - 1` unfortunately, by the look of things. Unless it's a typo in the OP's code.

Comment: @jarmod, indeed, I just noticed this. I saw _too_ much structure here, it seems

Comment: So, after changing the code so that 4,5,6,7,8, and 9 are in the correct spots, the code comes out to  if choice in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}:
        idx = choice - 1;
        print("\n", block[idx]);

Comment: @Jaxer6563, you could also simplify this to `if choice in range(1, 26+1)`

Comment: @ForceBru what is the +1 at then of the range for? it works with out that when i tried running it.

Comment: @Jaxer6563, the `+1` is needed to include the number `26` in the range. See: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: @ForceBru Ok, that makes more sense now, tried using 26 got my error catch thrown at me

Answer (score 3):

As another answer suggested, look for structure; you have different ranges of `choice`s that correspond to different offsets in `block`, so you can iterate over those:

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = input("Choose a block (Enter only the Number):")
    except ValueError:
        print("Thats not a number. Choose a number Numbnuts.")
        continue
    if choice < 1 or choice > 26:
        continue
    print("\n")
    for limit, offset in ((3, -1), (6, 2), (9, -4), (26, -1)):
        if choice <= limit:
            print(block[choice + offset])
            break
    break
```

Hence for `1 <= choice <= 3` you print `block[choice-1]`, for `4 <= choice <= 6` you print `block[choice+2]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

my version:

```
block_2 = block[:3]+block[6:9]+block[3:6]+block[9:]
print("\n", block_2[choice - 1])
```