# How to create a dictionary using fewer if-elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the program I'm revising, I'm making a calculator/dictionary. I'm stuck trying to take input, then give you a value for what materials are needed to craft the item, and then calculate how many items you need to craft that item in bulk.

[Original Calculator](https://github.com/GandalftheGreyt3719/ScrapMechanicCraftingCalculator):

```
ArmoredGlass = ("10 Glass, 2 Net Block, and 1 Ember for 10 Armored Glass [10 Sec. Craft Time]")
def blocks():
    print ("Here is the list of Craftable Blocks: \n")
    print ("Concrete1 \nWood1 \nMetal1 \nBarrierBlock \nTileBlock \nBrickBlock \nGlassBlock \nGlassTile \nPathLight \nCardBoard \nWood2 \nWood3 \nMetal2 \nMetal3 \nConcrete2 \nConcrete3 \nExtrudedMetal \nBubblePlastic \nCarpet \nNet \nSolidNet \nPunchedSteel \nRestroomBlock \nDiamondPlate \nSand \nArmoredGlass")
    time.sleep(2)
    while choice == 0:
        input_str = "\n \n Please choose a block to craft \n[ Please use same Capitalization and spaces] \n "
        choice = input(input_str)
        if choice == "Concrete1":
                print (Concrete1)
                ScrapStone = 5
                WaterEmpty = 5
                ChemicalEmpty = 5
                crafttime = 10

                singlecraft = 10

                craft = True
                bulk = True
        elif choice == "Wood1":
                print (Wood1)
                ScrapWood = 15
                crafttime = 10
                singlecraft = 10

                craft = True
                bulk = True
        elif choice == "Metal1":
                print (Metal1)
                ScrapMetal = 15
                crafttime = 10
                singlecraft = 10
```

etc.

[Revised Calculator](https://github.com/GandalftheGreyt3719/SMCalcRevised):

```
block = ["Concrete_1","Concrete_2","Concrete_3","Wood_1","Wood_2","Wood_3","Metal_1","Metal_2","Metal_3","Barrier_Block","Extruded_Metal","Tile_Block","Brick_Block","Glass_Block","Glass_Tile","Path_Light","Cardboard","Bubble_Plastic","Carpet","Net_Block","Solid_Net","Punched_Steel","Restroom_Block","Diamond_Plate","Sand","Armored_Glass"]
    for x in block:
        print(listitem, x)

        listitem += 1
        time.sleep(0.125)
    while choice == 0:
        choice = input("Choose a block (Enter only the Number):")
        if not choice.isalpha(): # Makes sure that the input is a number and not a string.
            choice = int(choice)
        else:
            choice = 0
            print("Thats not a number. Choose a number Numbnuts.")
        if choice in range (1,26+1): # reduces the if elif else chunk to a single if else statement. 26+1 allows 26 to be a value given, while allowing past the choice-1
            idx = choice - 1
            print("\n", block[idx])
        else:
            print("Please choose one of the given values.") # Error catch to prevent program from crashing due to a mispelled word or someone thinking their smart and trying to break the code
            choice = 0 # Resets the value to 0 so the loop repeats
```

The original used a bunch of if-elif statements, but I'm trying to cut down on those. It was possible with portions of the revision.

How do I create a dictionary using fewer if-elif statements?

Comment: You should ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Asking people to read through two separate repositories is not likely to give you much feedback. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but, you can create a dict like `items = {"concrete_1": {"ScrapStone": 5, "WaterEmpty": 5}}` and use `items[choice]` to access it, and maybe you should check out classes too

Comment: @Cagri So,  I would do the 26 dict entries, and then have it called by idx so that it matches the array value like `if items[1] == blocks[1]:` and then call on the concrete_1 definition?

Comment: What is the 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What does the rest of the post have to do with it? PS Please do not [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73650898/3404097). Clearly ask the 1 question you want an answer to. [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, Create a variable that will function as a dictionary.

```
block_craft
```

Then assign the block to be crafted, along with the values of required materials

```
block_craft = {"Concrete_1" : {"ScrapStone" : 5, "WaterEmpty" : 5, "ChemicalEmpty" : 5}}
```

Then go to where the choice and checker is located, and change it to look like this

```
if choice in range (1,26+1): 
            idx = choice - 1
            print("\n", block[idx])
            print("\n", block_craft[block[idx]])
```

Then when it is run, pass 1 to the input. It will give the first item, along with the correct definition.
Then, add a second craft item, with materials

```
block_craft = {"Concrete_1":{"ScrapStone" : 5, "WaterEmpty" : 5, "ChemicalEmpty" : 5}, "Concrete_2":{"Concrete1Empty" : 15, "Metal1Empty" : 2}}
```

Then, run it again, this time subbing 1 for 2. It should provide the correct item, along with the definition